# Why does python use by default almost 4MB of memory

Tags: python, linux, performance, memory

I'm currently doing some problems on [codeeval](https://www.codeeval.com/) and I'm using Python 2 (2.7.9 to be exact).

I'm constantly evaluated at 4MB in memory usage, so I did some tests with **valgrind**.

After multiple tests which all used somewhere around 4MB I decided to test something really simple:

```
valgrind python -c 'print 1'
```

Valgrind says:

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
total heap usage: 3,191 allocs, 2,995 frees, 3,462,538 bytes allocated
```

Is there a possibility to get this any lower? Or is this some kind of a default for my Python installation on my machine (x86_64, Ubuntu 15.04).

Comment: The Python interpreter will take up memory, as will libraries.  4MB?  Why are you worried about that?

Comment: Interpreter, builtins, interned integers, ...

Comment: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Objects/obmalloc.c#l27

Comment: Not really worried, I mean for my day to day scripts it doesn't matter, I was just wandering if it's possible to get that lower (for the competition's sake :D)

Comment: Then Python's probably not the language for you!